# Apache Spark streaming simple application not working

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

i've the following issue on Apache Spark Streaming library. I've rewrite a simple "word count" stand alone application to see how the streaming works, so here the code:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount");
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(1000));

    // Create a DStream that will connect to hostname:port, like localhost:9999
    JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = jssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999);

    // Split each line into words
    JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(
      new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
        @Override public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
          return Arrays.asList(x.split(" "));
        }
      });

    // Count each word in each batch
    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(
      new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
        @Override public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) throws Exception {
          return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
        }
      });



    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(
      new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) throws Exception {
          return i1 + i2;
        }
      });

    // Print the first ten elements of each RDD generated in this DStream to the console
    wordCounts.print();

    jssc.start();              // Start the computation
    jssc.awaitTermination();   // Wait for the computation to terminate
```

When i run this stand alone application the logs loops the following lines:

```
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1412767004000 ms.0 from job set of time 1412767004000 ms
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.023 s for time 1412767004000 ms (execution: 0.019 s)
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO ShuffledRDD: Removing RDD 428 from persistence list
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 428
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO MappedRDD: Removing RDD 427 from persistence list
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 427
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO FlatMappedRDD: Removing RDD 426 from persistence list
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 426
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO BlockRDD: Removing RDD 425 from persistence list
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO SocketInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[425] at BlockRDD at ReceiverInputDStream.scala:69 of time 1412767004000 ms
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 425
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO SocketReceiver: Stopped receiving
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO SocketReceiver: Closed socket to localhost:9999
14/10/08 13:16:44 WARN ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Restarting receiver with delay 2000 ms: Retrying connecting to localhost:9999
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopping receiver with message: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Retrying connecting to localhost:9999: 
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver onStop
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Deregistering receiver 0
14/10/08 13:16:44 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Retrying connecting to localhost:9999
14/10/08 13:16:44 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopped receiver 0
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1412767005000 ms
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1412767005000 ms.0 from job set of time 1412767005000 ms
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: take at DStream.scala:608
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 435 (map at MappedDStream.scala:35)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 217 (take at DStream.scala:608) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=true)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 433(take at DStream.scala:608)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(Stage 434)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 433 (ShuffledRDD[436] at combineByKey at ShuffledDStream.scala:42), which has no missing parents
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2256) called with curMem=23776, maxMem=277842493
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_217 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.2 KB, free 264.9 MB)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from Stage 433 (ShuffledRDD[436] at combineByKey at ShuffledDStream.scala:42)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 433.0 with 1 tasks
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 433.0 (TID 217, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1008 bytes)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 433.0 (TID 217)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO BlockFetcherIterator$BasicBlockFetcherIterator: maxBytesInFlight: 50331648, targetRequestSize: 10066329
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO BlockFetcherIterator$BasicBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO BlockFetcherIterator$BasicBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 433.0 (TID 217). 822 bytes result sent to driver
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 433.0 (TID 217) in 4 ms on localhost (1/1)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Stage 433 (take at DStream.scala:608) finished in 0.006 s
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 433.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: take at DStream.scala:608, took 0.009386933 s
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: take at DStream.scala:608
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO MapOutputTrackerMaster: Size of output statuses for shuffle 108 is 82 bytes
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 218 (take at DStream.scala:608) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=true)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 435(take at DStream.scala:608)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(Stage 436)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 435 (ShuffledRDD[436] at combineByKey at ShuffledDStream.scala:42), which has no missing parents
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2256) called with curMem=26032, maxMem=277842493
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_218 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.2 KB, free 264.9 MB)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from Stage 435 (ShuffledRDD[436] at combineByKey at ShuffledDStream.scala:42)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 435.0 with 1 tasks
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 435.0 (TID 218, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1008 bytes)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 435.0 (TID 218)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO BlockFetcherIterator$BasicBlockFetcherIterator: maxBytesInFlight: 50331648, targetRequestSize: 10066329
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO BlockFetcherIterator$BasicBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO BlockFetcherIterator$BasicBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 1 ms
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 435.0 (TID 218). 822 bytes result sent to driver
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 435.0 (TID 218) in 3 ms on localhost (1/1)
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 435.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Stage 435 (take at DStream.scala:608) finished in 0.003 s
14/10/08 13:16:45 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: take at DStream.scala:608, took 0.008348754 s
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1412767005000 ms
-------------------------------------------
```

and on web UI i can see the follow screenshot:

[image]

obviously the netcat -lk 9999 doesn't do anything when i write some example words.

Can someone help me to figure out how make this example works?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As given in the comment

run

```
nc -lk 9999 in console
```

Then run the following command inside the spark folder

```
bin/run-example org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.JavaNetworkWordCount localhost 9999
```

Now add words in the tab of console where you run nc

```
It is working! Life is beautiful!
```

and check the output, in the spark folder

```
(beautiful!,1)
(working!,1)
(is,2)
(It,1)
(Life,1)
```

If you keep adding , it program will continue to consolidate..
Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You need to open one port for communication in your local system by using this command

```
nc -lk 9999
```

then after spark get all the text from the console (port 9999) as a stream.